# Send adaptive card to a user in MS Teams when a user successfully saved a record on our Web App

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-teams

I want to send an adaptive card notification to a specific user in Microsoft Teams when a user successfully saved a record on our Web Application. Is there a way to do this using C#? I am thinking of calling an API to do this but I don't know how to start..

EDIT: Incoming webhooks only applies on Teams Channel and I need this notification to be sent on the App that I published on Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Have you looked through the integrations Microsoft provides for MS Teams? Incoming Webhooks or Notification Bots? Your question is far too broad as it currently stands, see [ask].

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry about that. Incoming Webhooks I think only applies to Teams Channel. I am actually talking about the Notification bot App that I published to Microsoft Teams. I want an adaptive card to be sent on that App when a user saved a record on our Web Application

Comment: Are you looking for the same-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed-broadcast/csharp